# Is it possible to use 2-step verification with multiple accounts on a phone?

Tags: google-account, google-authenticator, 2-step-verification

Using 2-step verification with Google Authenticator on an Android handset provides good security for accessing Gmail and other Google services.  What I am curious about is whether Google Authenticator can provide support for all Gmail accounts on the phone (multiple Gmail accounts can be added to a single handset under the Accounts menu in Settings).  Will both accounts authenticate using the same codes?

Comment: I know that the Authenticator app does allow for manually entering accounts. I haven't yet set up a second account with 2-step authentication, though.

Comment: It supports third-party account too. For example, I use it for LastPass 2-step authentication..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Android as well as Blackberry versions of Google's Authenticator app supports multiple accounts.

Press MENU and choose SCAN BARCODE after you've set up your new Google Account for 2-factor auth to grab the displayed barcode or enter details manually.

Details: https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/

Answer (score 2):

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator

> Google Authenticator creates two-step verification codes on your phone.
>
> Google Authenticator works with 2-step verification for your Google Account to provide an additional layer of security.
>
> Features:
>
> - Automatic setup via QR code
> - **Support for multiple accounts**
> - Time and counter based code generation
>
> To use this app, you need to enable 2-step verification on your Google Account.

Answer (score 0):

Google Authenticator, as well as other 2FA applications, support multiple accounts (not only Google services). In the process of token enrollment, you will be asked to scan the QR code. Based on this QR codes Google Authenticator generates one-time passwords. As QR codes are different OTPs generated by the app are also different. You should create a new token for each account.